Sharing a ModelContainer Instance Between App and WidgetBundle Targets in swiftui
I am encountering an issue when attempting to share the same ModelContainer instance between two separate targets: App and WidgetBundle. To achieve this, I created a StorageController to manage the ModelContainer and injected it into both targets.
// StorageController.swift
@MainActor
public static var globalInstance: StorageController = StorageController()

let modelContainer: ModelContainer
let modelContext: ModelContext

@MainActor
init() {
  do {
    let schema = Schema([
      Item.self,
    ])
    let config = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
    modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: config)
    modelContext = modelContainer.mainContext
    Logger().info("init modelContainer")

    guard let urlApp = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else { return }
    let url = urlApp.appendingPathComponent("default.store")
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
      Logger().info("swiftdata db at \(url.absoluteString)")
    } else {
      Logger().warning("can't find swiftdata db")
    }
  } catch {
    fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
  }
}

// MyWidgetExtentionBundle.swift
@main
struct MyWidgetExtentionBundle: WidgetBundle {
  @MainActor
  init() {
    Logger().info("MyWidgetExtentionBundle init")
    let sc = StorageController.globalInstance

    AppDependencyManager.shared.add(dependency: sc)
  }

  var body: some Widget {
    MyWidgetExtention()
  }
}

// AppIntentsInWidgetExtentionApp.swift
@main
struct AppIntentsInWidgetExtentionApp: App {
  @State
  private var storageController: StorageController

  init() {
    let sc = StorageController.globalInstance
    storageController = sc
  }

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack {
        Text("Total item cnt:\(storageController.fetchItems().count)")
        Button("Add Item") {
          storageController.addItem(name: "Item-\(UUID().uuidString)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


However, after adding logging to verify the location of the ModelContainer store file, I found that two different default.store files are being created.
# start with App
swiftdata db at file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99106351-788D-4605-A5E6-475AD73ED05C/data/Library/Application%20Support/default.store
# start with WidgetBundle
swiftdata db at file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99106351-788D-4605-A5E6-475AD73ED05C/data/Containers/Data/Application/7465C92B-AC5A-4AB0-BA68-2EEB78C16A38/Library/Application%20Support/default.store

What is the correct approach to ensure that the ModelContainer is shared between the App and WidgetBundle targets, so that data remains synchronized?

It turns out that the system treats the App and WidgetBundle as separate processes, preventing them from sharing containers. To enable container sharing across targets, follow the guide on using the App Groups feature.
